# How can i redirect from page, which sends a registration email, to the same page in browser again

Tags: php, email, session, redirect

is there a way to redirect to the same open tab in browser from a registration mail??
And work with the same session ??
I guess there must be ... because i just signed in here in stackoverflow ... and it was doing exactly that. (I think)

I am trying to do the same with php.
I want the user to be able to register via the link - the easy way.
But also during the order process.
Which means i already have a session running with CART and Customer information to which i want to redirect of course.

Thanks.

Comment: *"is there a way to redirect to the same open tab in browser from a registration mail??"* I doubt that very very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to send an email to a user from a web page and, when the user checks their email and follows a link within it, have it open that new page in the same exact tab they originally generated the email from.

Fortunately, there **isn't** a way to set focus a specific tab or a window. This would be an ad providers dream, which is why it is not possible to do.

What you could do is [set a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) storing the information you wish to save about the user so when they do eventually come back, you would be able to check for the cookie and reference any information you stored about their visit in the cookie.

Comment: ... or simply have a session active. As long as the domain names match, the browser will continue the session when the user clicks the link in the E-Mail.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, unless the user closes the browser between checking the mail and coming back, which is a possibility.

Comment: okay great ... so that means if i have a session running and get to the SAME URL again from where the registration mail was sent... it should work ??

Comment: my problem is .. when i confirm registration via mail ... and get back .. the shoppingcart is empty, where in the original tab the cart is filled with products.

Comment: @user are you sure you are on the exact same domain? (`www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are different domains)